# django unique filename extra argument

Tags: python, django

I want to make my file names unique to prevent collide.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=unique_string_generator, unique=True, blank=True)
```

this is my field.

```
def unique_string_generator(instance: any, filename: str, *, path: str) -> str:
"""

:param instance: Instance to pass
:param filename: filename of the uploaded file
:param path: path where to upload
:return: where the file will be uploaded
"""
extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
unique_value = uuid.uuid4()
filename = f'{unique_value}-{instance.pk}.{extension}'
return os.path.join(path, filename)
```

This is my function, how can I pass

> path='somewhere'

to field, because django takes my function as an arguement. 
A small question, what should be passed for annotation django instance? I just passed

> instance: any

because I couldn't figure out what to annotate?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation, I believe you can get help from python itself. I mean you can just check the type of the instance with `type()` function. With debugging tools or just a `print()` statement it'll be all clear.

By the way, **djangoproject** docs has a [description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) about `upload_to`'s `instance` argument:

> An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. More
>   specifically, this is the particular instance where the current file
>   is being attached.
>
> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database
>   yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a
>   value for its primary key field.

---

**TL;DR**

So, in this case, the type of the `instance` argument is the model (class) containing this ImageField.

For example, if the `ImageField` is inside `User` model, the type of instance would be `<class 'appname.models.User'>`.

```
def unique_string_generator(instance: User, ...) -> str:
    ...
```